# Can one upload a csv file to postgres via pgadmin, without specifying column names beforehand?

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

Im trying to use the PgAdminn III Import tool and want to upload a .csv file. I dont know the column names OR column numbers beforehand, and would like to have them be populated on the fly. I also know that the number of columns is consistent across rows.

Answer (score 0):

In the sense of having a table dynamically created for you from the CSV, no, not with PgAdmin-III or `psql`.

You'll want to write a quick script for that with your preferred scripting language + its PostgreSQL driver interface, or use an ETL tool like CloverETL, Pentaho Kettle, or Talend Studio.